# How do I pass bound data to nested selections in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build and update a table using D3 selectors, but I'm having issues with updating my rows after creation. The following code tries to bind the rows in the table to some incoming `[Object]`, each with `name` and `value` fields.

```
var table = d3.select("#dataTable");

var binding = table.selectAll("tr.data")
  .data(data, function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

var enterBinding = binding.enter();
var updateBinding = binding;  

updateBinding.selectAll("td").text(function(d) {
  if(d3.select(this).classed("name")) {
    return d.name;
  } else {
    return d.value;
  }
});

var newRows = enterBinding.append("tr").classed("data", true);
newRows.append("td")
  .classed("name", true)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });
newRows.append("td")
  .classed("value", true)
  .text(function(d) {
    return JSON.stringify(d.value);
  });
```

The rows get created properly, and with the right data. The update selection does occur and my handlers are called but the data presented to the anonymous function (supplied to `updateBinding.selectAll.text` above) is old and never changes.

Can i not depend on nested selections on `binding` to contain up to date data the way I'm using it here?

Is there a better way to update nested elements like my `<td>`s?

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful. Could you clarify "..the data presented to the anonymous function is old and never changes"? What's the anonymous function being called? Are there any console errors?

Comment: The selection produced by `updateBinding.selectAll('td')` above does not supply current data to the function in the subsequent `.text()` call. Apparently the `selectAll` accesses the parent's data before the new binding is applied.

Comment: I've modified my code to manually call `html()` on the `tr` selection and that works. If no one can point me to a more canonical way to update a table row I will self-post that one as an answer for others to find. Surprises me that there isn't a canonical table update example somewhere for d3.

Comment: It looks like you're not updating your `d` datum after new rows are added to the table. D3 isn't doing two-way binding like "angular" or "knockout" (as far as I know.) I'd suggest writing a function that reconstitutes your table data when additions are made, and just call it when new rows are added.

Comment: The `updateBinding` only contains existing rows that need their data updated. At the `tr` level the data is correct, but once i do an additional selection it becomes out of date.

Comment: See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/LeeMendelowitz/11383724).

Comment: Do you think this is better than manually setting `.html()` on the `tr`? It seems like it would be less clear what was going on to other people reading the code. I will spend some time looking at it.